# Visual Studio 2012 + Resharper 7.1 = slooooow, what to do?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

I used to have R# 6 with VS2010 and it was great.

Now I installed yesterday R# 7.1 trial and my VS 2012 became slow to the point I really 
want to uninstall R# despite all the heartache involved with it.

Any advices on how to troubleshoot this performance issue?

Comment: You should have a look at this link [Ultimate Guide to Speeding Up ReSharper (and Visual Studio)](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Ultimate+Guide+to+Speeding+Up+ReSharper+%28and+Visual+Studio%29)

Answer (score 2):

Please be more specific: what kind of projects do you work with, did you notice which particular actions are slow (for example, opening a solution, invoking code completion (IntelliSense) in JavaScript or something like this). Without details I can only give you these general advises:

1. Close Visual Studio, try to delete your solution caches (they are usually located near your *.sln file, in folder named like _ReSharper.), open Visual Studio again.
2. Try to temporaty disable/uninstall all other Visual Studio extensions/plugins.
3. Try ReSharper 8.0 EAP, maybe your issue is fixed there.
4. ReSharper has a feature that allows you to profile it (menu ReSharper | Help | Profile Visual Studio). If you know a reproducible slow action, you can invoke this feature, make this action and then send this performance snapshot to JetBrains support (http://www.jetbrains.com/support/resharper/) or open a bugreport at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/. They could tell you which part of ReSharper is slow and how to disable that part.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot pin down a specific action. It is an overall feeling, as if there are background tasks affecting the responsiveness of the UI.

Comment: @mark Is typing slow? Try to quickly type several characters. If they are slow to appear, then it's a concrete example, you can profile it and send us a snapshot.

Comment: I was probably too fast posting the question. It seems to be OK now, after a couple of days. I will wait a bit more to see if there are any problems.